# Guest Metrics in Azure for Kubernetes based VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-container-service, azure-aks

We have an application which monitors the performance of the VM's by gathering metrics and running some analysis.

We obtain the memory metrics from the Azure Storage Accounts "WADMetrics" table.

Recently we added some **Kubernetes** based VM's and enabled "Basic Metrics" and "Boot Diagnostics"

But even after enabling metrics we don't see any Guest metrics. Only Host metrics are available.

Does anyone know the reason.Do we have to do something for Kubernetes based VM's to report Guest metrics ?

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: define guest metrics?

Comment: For example in Azure portal 'Memory Used', 'Memory Available' etc.

Comment: it doesnt matter if vm is kubernetes or not. the agent doesnt care about that

Comment: I don't see any of the guest utilization metrics in the Azure portal for a Kubernetes based VM.